# VBA Spliting Code and passing arguments

Tags: vba, pass-by-reference

I'm quite a beginner at coding and the problem that I'm having is that the procedure is too large. I read that this can be fixed by dividing the code into smaller modules. However I want to know if the values of the variables defined outside the modules can be taken into account when you call the variable inside the modules to modify it. Also, after being modified can you use the new value outside the module and in another module? Can someone explain me how the VBA works in these cases? Thank you so much.

I read the answer you gave me but while i understand the concept there is no example that fit my case. I would really appreciate an example so I can fully understand how to solve my issue. What i have is basically:

```
sub simulador()

Sheets(2).Activate

With ActiveSheet

a=1
b=1
c=1

for t=2 to 20

procedure using and modifying variables a and c
b=cells(t,15)

for a=2 to 20
code using variable b
next a

d=3
j=9

procedure using the variables a b and j
for ga=2 to 20
code using variable d
next ga

next t
end with
end sub
```

And what i need to do is create a sub1 whit:

```
procedure using and modifying variables a and c
b=cells(t,15)
```

A sub 2 whit:

```
for a=2 to 20
code using and modifying variable b
next a
```

An sub 3 whit:

```
procedures using the variables a b and j
for ga=2 to 20
code using variable d
next ga
```

So at the end would be like:

```
sub simulador()

Sheets(2).Activate

With ActiveSheet

a=1
b=1
c=1

for t=2 to 20

Call sub 1 

Call sub 2

d=3
j=9

Call sub 3 

next t
end with
end sub
```

In all the cases i want to call the subroutines passing the variables Byref so once they are modified stay modified so another sub can use them with the new value. Also the active sheet should remain active when the procedures in those subroutines are executed. I can't figure out how everything works exactly. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

I don't have the will to spend time in explain how this works, because these are there very basics of programming, so.... search on google this:

> vb function passing parameter difference byref and byval